# Why is there an upper limit on MicroSD card adapter?

Tags: macbook, adapter, memory-card

I'm currently searching for a MicroSD adapter for my MacBook. I saw several adapters satisfying my condition.

But most of them had an upper limit on the storage size they support. ([Example](http://www.flipkart.com/f2s-micro-sd-tf-card-slot-adapter-macbook-air-pro-upto-128-gb-reader/p/itmecztb4pw62w9x?pid=CDRECZTBXQDDXH4Y&ref=L%3A7628000232085015590&srno=p_1&query=MacBook%20MicroSD%20&otracker=from-search))

This is quite strange since the only job of this adapter is to connect two pins, my macbook's and the memory card's.

Can anyone please explain why is it not simple as that? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I can only guess that it lists the highest capacity at the time it was made and tested, but offering no guarantee of future compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that they're advertising to the uninformed who will go "but I have a big one; will it work?" and so they advertise to the largest µSD card available at the time.

Comment: So, there's actually no limit on the memory card size which an adapter can support? Can you please confirm it? :)

Comment: I can't, but this guy can: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrvGzoGMEY0

Comment: Thank you. Misleading information on almost all websites.